# constexpr class in VC++14 (Visual Studio 2015) cannot be brace initialized

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, constexpr

I came across an interesting anomaly today that only happens in VC++14 (constexpr is not supported in predecessors).

Here is a minimal example:

This compiles

```
struct constClass {
    constexpr constClass() = default;
};

static constexpr constClass cclass = constClass();

int main()
{ }
```

but this refuses to:

```
struct constClass {
    constexpr constClass() = default;
};

static constexpr constClass cclass = constClass{};
//                                              * only difference - uses {} instead of ()

int main()
{ }
```

Is this a bug that I should submit, or is there something that I don't know?

Both these code samples compile in GCC and Clang.

Comment: `static constexpr constClass cclass;` and `static constexpr constClass cclass{};` and `static constexpr constClass cclass = {};` also work.

Comment: @melak47 interesting. Imma submit this a bug

Comment: heres the bug report. Well see what mcft does here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1842202/constexpr-variables-cannot-be-initialized-using-braces-in-a-constructor